# after.each_scenario hook is not working(not available) in aloe_django

Tags: django, python-3.x, bdd, lettuce

I wanted to do some operations(clear cookies, clear database etc) after each scenario in one feature, but the after.each_feature is not available in aloe_django. How did you deal with this problem. Any suggestions to handle this. The following hook is not available in aloe_django.

`@before.each_scenario
 def setup_some_scenario(scenario):
    populate_test_database()`

I need this because I want to have several scenarios in one feature, when first feature is completed I log out from admin and need to log in again in the next scenario(not logging out does not help), but in the next scenario it gives an error telling that my credentials are not valid(in the first scenario it was valid). 
When I put this scenarios as different feature and reset my db and migrate it works fine.

I think when it jumps from one scenario to another within the feature it messes up the db or uses different one, so I need after.each_scenario() hook to reset and migrate my db.

Comment: put some code thats why other dev. can understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have used before/after.each_example() hook available in Aloe_django.
You put this piece of code into your terrain.py file.

`@before.each_example
     def before_each_example(scenario,outline,steps):
        call_command(#your command#)`

Answer (score 0):

```
You could use @After tag, 

Example:

@Clean up
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left |
    |  12   |  5  |  7   |
    |  20   |  5  |  15  |

In step definition,

@After("Clean up")
public void cleanup(){

System.out.println("CLEAN UP RUNNING ");

}


After every scenario, Your test will call this after function and do cleaning job.
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have resolved my issue with each_example() hook available in aloe

Comment: Please comment entire solution. It will help others.

Comment: have commited more precise answer